# What is the solution to Firebase onTokenRefresh not being called on-time [Android]?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have coded my Android app in such a way that I need the device token to be available upon first launch. (The user will login/signup and I need to send this token together with the login/signup request to the server.)

However, I noticed that onTokenRefresh is not yet even called when I need the device token. It is the same in both the emulator and a real device. What can be the solution to my problem? Can I obtain a device token on demand? Or could it be something to do with requesting permission to force a device token to be generated?

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) says "*On initial startup of your app, the FCM SDK generates a registration token for the client app instance. If you want to target single devices or create device groups, you'll need to access this token by extending FirebaseInstanceIdService.*" However, I noticed that it is not generated on time when I need it and there's seems to be no guarantee that it is available when I need it.

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: Can you remove dependency of login/signUp with firebase token? I mean send your token lazy, after your token has been generated you sent it to server.

Comment: This would be a sad solution to my problem. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perhaps sure that token would be generated at very starting of the app. This token would not be re-generate / re-create without some conditions to fulfill.
You can store this token using **sharedpreference** and can use later.
I am doing like this and seems getting token for users when I need.

****If token refresh takes that much long time then you could update user info later after getting token. - **This could be the safest solution to avoid null value**.

In my sense update user info all time after app launching (if token value not null) and store token value in sharedpreference inside

> onTokenRefresh()

that user value would be always updated if it changes in any situation.

Comment: It is not generated in time for me. When I tried to retrieve it, it is a null. I see that it is generated much later

Comment: check, I think it will help

Comment: There are 2 solutions: (1) temporarily store messages on server waiting to be pushed if there is no token. (2) just skip sending push messages if there is no token received from  Android devices.

Answer (score 1):

You could call `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` everytime you need the token. It works pretty fine for me.

Comment: `This method returns null if the token has not yet been generated.`

Answer (score 0):

Just use this in your onCreate method of your launcher activity

```
String id=FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()
```

and pass this id where you wannna use